# Roll back changes made by mistake in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007, office-2007, rollback

While using Microsoft Excel 2007, something weird happened and all the names after the *nth* row change to ABCD and I saved the file by mistake. How do I bring back the old names which have changed to ABCD?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a copy or back-up, it may be possible to use features of your operating system.

Comment: i dont have a back up. how can i get it back?

Comment: Things are bad when you do not have back-ups. If you right-click the file and choose properties, do you see a Previous Versions tab? If so, that may help. You might also like to post on http://superuser.com/ before you try anything.